# Using autofs to mount a NFS share

Tags: linux, rhel, autofs

I am trying to setup a RHEL 7 machine with an `autofs` NFS mount (the NFS mount is a Windows 2012 R2 server running Services for NFS).

Here are the contents of /etc/auto.master:

```
/nfs /etc/auto.nfs
```

Here are the contents of `/etc/auto.nfs`:

```
nfs -fstype=nfs,rw,soft,intr 10.0.2.15:/share
```

I have run `service autofs restart` as well as rebooting the RHEL machine.

I can ping 10.0.2.15 successfully. From 10.0.2.15, I can ping my RHEL box.

The NFS mount is shared in `C:\share` on the 10.0.2.15. I have added full control permissions for the RHEL machine.

When trying to connect to the NFS mount using mount.nfs, I receive the below error message:

```
mount.nfs: Connection timed out.
```

the log file: `/var/log/messages` does not show anything helpful.

Comment: This sounds like your issue: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2010/08/18/getting-rpc-timed-out-while-accessing-nfs-share-from-unix-client.aspx